# Confusing Definition of field in Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra done right. What does "1+1 is defined to equal 0" in the definition of field mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the 2015th edition of the book, linear algebra done right. Sheldon axler, defines a field to be

```
A field is a set containing at least two distinct elements called 0 and 1, along
with operations of addition and multiplication satisfying all the properties
listed in 1.3. Thus R and C are fields, as is the set of rational numbers along
with the usual operations of addition and multiplication. Another example of
a field is the set {0, 1} with the usual operations of addition and multiplication
except that 1 + 1 is defined to equal 0.
```

In the last sentence he says, `except that 1 + 1 is defined to equal 0`.

I don't understand what this means, in the context of a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero element $0$ and unit element $1$ of a field $F$ form itself a field $P=\{0,1\}$ if the addition is defined such that $1+1=0$. This is the prime field with two elements usually denoted by ${\Bbb Z}_2$ (as ring) or $GF(2)$ (as Galois field).

Comment: Correct, but $0$ and $1$ are not, a priori, elements of a field. They are just symbols. We could have written $a$ and $b$ instead, and said that, by definition, $a+a=a, a+b=b$ and $b+b=a$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro can you verify my comment on the answer by José Carlos Santos.

Answer (score 1):

Sheldon is talking about the field $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$, for which we have$$0+0=0,\ 0+1=1,\, 1+0=1\text{, and }1+1=0$$and$$0\times0=0,\ 0\times1=0,\ 1\times0=0\text{, and }1\times1=1.$$

Comment: okay so since there is no other element in the field ({0, 1}) except 0 and 1, 1+1 will go to the next possible element in the field but since there's none, it goes back to 0. right?

Comment: No. It's because $1+1=1\iff1+1=1+0\implies1=0$ but, *by definition*, in a field you always have $1\neq0$.

Comment: can you simply this explanation a bit further, I'm still confused.

Comment: In any field, you have$$a+b=a+c\implies b=c.$$In particular, if we had $1+1=1$, we would have $1+1=1+0$, but then it would follow from the rule above that $1=0$, which cannot happen, by the definition of field.